# Swiper loop not working as intended for video carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, carousel, swiper.js

I'm making a video carousel which loops each time it progressive bar reaches it end,the video plays perfectly, but the loop attribute in swiper doesn't seem to work, Here is the code

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Pagination, A11y, type Swiper as SwiperRef } from 'swiper';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';

import ship from '../assets/videos/ship.mp4'
import highway from '../assets/videos/pexels-kelly-lacy-5473765.mp4'


import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';


const NewHome = () => {
  return (

   <Swiper
        modules={[ Pagination , A11y]}
        autoplay={{ delay: 5000}}
        pagination={{ clickable: true }}
        loop
        className="w-1/2"
      >
        <SwiperSlide>
          <video width="900" height="800" autoPlay muted loop>
            <source src={ship} type='video/mp4'/>
          </video>
        </SwiperSlide>
       

        <SwiperSlide>
          <video src={highway} width="900" height="800"/>
        </SwiperSlide>
    </Swiper>
  )
}

export default NewHome
```

CSS

```
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.swiper-container + .swiper-container {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* outline: 1px red solid; */
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet-active::before {
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-animation: slide-progress 2s cubic-bezier(0.3, 0, 0.3, 1) forwards;
          animation: slide-progress 2s cubic-bezier(0.3, 0, 0.3, 1) forwards;
}
.swiper-paused .swiper-pagination-bullet-active::before {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
          animation-play-state: paused;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-progress {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-progress {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

I tried adding a delay option to the autoplay but its still didn't work, I expect it switch to the next video after the progress bar of each slide reaches it end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, so I forgot to import the Autoplay module from swiper and now it works perfectly fine

Note:
You'll also need to import the css file for the autoplay module in order to make it work

Answer (score 0):

The `loop` property of the Swiper component may not be working because the videos have their own `loop` attribute.
If you loop your videos they cannot trigger the `Swiper` component to move to the next slide.

Try removing loop from `video` and rely on Swiper component's loop:

```
<SwiperSlide>
  <video width="900" height="800" autoPlay muted> // removed loop
    <source src={ship} type='video/mp4'/>
  </video>
</SwiperSlide>
```

Comment: I have done that but it is still not working

Comment: How about removing `loop` from `Swiper` component and letting them stay in `video`?

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of the slide, each of these videos are quite lengthy, that is why I would want the loop to occur in a fixed duration. Although taking out the loop hasn't solved it

Comment: Can you provide a sandbox to your issue? I would like to play around with the code